# Automatically take a picture to proceed on back thread when rectangle detected? iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, rectangles

I am working on a project at the moment and wanted to find out what I need to be looking at to automatically take a picture when a rectangle is detected. I have seen this in action on an app called car spotter but wanted to know how it could be done. On car spotter it detects the rectangle and blurs the number plate automatically.

Comment: You could try  OpenCV: https://www.toptal.com/machine-learning/real-time-object-detection-using-mser-in-ios

Comment: This question as it stands it too broad and potentially opinion-based. Please refine your question to a particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AVCaptureSession` to capture pictures from camera, and use `CIDetector` to detect rectangle. They are all system APIs, doesn't need OpenCV which costs extra storage space.

And there is an implementation example on Github: 
 https://github.com/charlymr/IRLDocumentScanner

And the key procedures are in this class:
https://github.com/charlymr/IRLDocumentScanner/blob/master/Source/Private/IRLCameraView.m